# Show adMob banners only in specific scenes; Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, banner

In my game I got 4 different Scenes.
Now I want to ad some AdMob banners, but just in 2 of these 4 scenes.

I tried it like this.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {


var bannerView: GADBannerView!



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()


    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'

        if var scene = StartScene(fileNamed: "StartScene") {





            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)



        }



        if var scene = MainMenuScene(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene") {



        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

        self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.delegate = self
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-2567181742111069/9977523039"
        bannerView.load(request)
        bannerView.center = CGPoint(x: 329, y: 350)

        }


        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsPhysics = false


        view.showsFPS = false
        view.showsNodeCount = false



      }



}
```

The problem is, that the ads are still shown in every Scene.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ads show in every scene because the bannerview is attached to the GameViewController (acting as the super view), which holds the child scenes.

Create and load the banner ads in `viewDidLoad()` and hide it in scenes you don't want it to appear in, then show it in scenes you want:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {


var bannerView: GADBannerView!



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

        self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.delegate = self
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-2567181742111069/9977523039"
        bannerView.load(request)
        bannerView.center = CGPoint(x: 329, y: 350)


    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'

        if var scene = StartScene(fileNamed: "StartScene") {

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            self.bannerView.isHidden = true
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }



        if var scene = MainMenuScene(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene") {

                self.bannerView.isHidden = false

        }


        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsPhysics = false


        view.showsFPS = false
        view.showsNodeCount = false



      }

}
```

You can also use the `addSubView` and `removeFromSuperview` functions to add/remove from the superview(GameViewController) and its window